# Can NTFS-Search(An OSS project) scan any file on NTFS volume?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I want to apply [NTFS-Search](http://ntfs-search.sourceforge.net/) to our project.
Our project have to find the files which we specified.(fast and exactly!)

But I'm not sure the program(NTFS-Search) works well.
What if the specified file is system file?
What if the file is being opened by a process with NO_READ_SHARE_MODE?

Do you think NTFS-Search can find any files?
I don't know about NTFS filesystem well.
So I can't find the answer myself.

Is there anyone who knows that?

I tried to find their email address, but I couldn't find.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description of that project it just scans the MFT for a specified file name. This means that neither the file attributes nor its share flags for open files should make any difference.

You can contact the developer on their [user page at sf.net](http://sourceforge.net/users/thgr32), by the way.

Comment: I didn't know what MFT means.  
And I've tried to contact him. Thanks Johannes :)

Comment: But, isn't there any other problem? what do you think?

Comment: You can read the source code if you need to know how it works exactly. It doesn't seem to be very long or complex. The only thing I wondered was whether you can get easy access to the MFT without obtaining a volume handle for which you would need administrative privileges. That would make the approach useless on most modern Windows systems.